# I loss the listitem which was added to list using Item Added Event Receiver

Tags: permissions, event-handlers, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am using this code to break the permission.But i loss the listitem after refresh the page.Plz help me..

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)

        {

  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.Web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists["SampleEvent"];
                        SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                        SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(84);//i am getting the added item by hardcoding the id
                        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                        {
                            item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                        }
                        item.Update();
                   }
                }
            });
         }
```

Comment: What you lost... Item with id `84`?

Comment: yes.i lost the list item 84

Comment: plz help me...i want solution for this...

Comment: I tried with the same code what you mentioned. But I am able to see my item. My Item is not deleting

Comment: Change the item id to some other and try once and check for that also is it behaving same or not?

Comment: I am created list with name SampleEvent.And i gave contribute permission for 2 user.I try to break all the permission customly. If i add any listitem means,it remain in the list.But the 2 user login into the list and added listitem means,it was not able to view by that users.But i can able to see the listitem which was added by them...

Comment: r u able to understand my issue???

Comment: For every item it behave like this ly

Comment: I checked with administrator privilege only. In that case it works fine

Comment: what i have to do????Then y i lost the listitem???

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And why do you hardcode item 84 in the code?

Comment: I want to break the permission customly for particular listitem.So i took 84 th listitem.

Answer (score 1):

For a standard user your code will remove access item 84 (Hard coded????)

You're calling [SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.breakroleinheritance.aspx) with the parameter false, which means break role inheritance without copying any permissions. The result of this will be that nobody has access to the item. Except for site collection admins (and persons granted access at web app level).

Usually you'll follow the call to BreakRoleInheritance with adding some permissions. See [How to: Break Role Assignment Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx)

Your code is similar to an priviledged user doing the following in the UI:

1. Go to the list.
2. Select Item 84.
3. Click Item permissions.
4. Click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
5. Select all users/groups.
6. Click Remove User Permissions

In the comment you state that users should only be allowed to see Items they've created themselves. If that's your requirement then you don't need an event receiver. Instead do the following:

1. Go to the list
2. In the ribbon select List Settings
3. Click Advanced Settings
4. Set Item-level permissions like this:
   [image]
5. Click OK

The same can be achived programatically by setting [SPList.ReadSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.readsecurity.aspx) and [SPList.WriteSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity.aspx)

If this isn't enough and you need specific rights to each item then read [How to: Work with Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535915.aspx) and [How to: Break Role Assignment Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx)

Comment: Hi..can u plz give more explanation abt this.

Comment: I've adden a discription of what the similar actions in the UI would be. What are you trying to do? Which user(s) should have access to the item after you're done. And why item 84?

Comment: k...i understood what u trying to tel.

Comment: k...i understood what u trying to tel.My requirement is:I have one list.Consider 'A' and 'B' are the user.An listitem added by 'A' is not shown to 'B'.Likewise 'A' is not able to see the listitem which was added by 'B'.

Comment: Item 84 is..I am just taking one listitem and try to apply my requirement.Just for testing i took one listitem

Comment: Plz help me....

Comment: Added info about List Item-Level permissions to answer

Comment: Thanx for ur answer.But i need programatically.

Comment: k.How to get current login user.I'm always getting SharePoint\\System as Login name becoz of RunWithElevatedPrivileges.

Comment: `properties.Web.CurrentUser` or if you want login name `properties.UserLoginName`

Comment: thanx a lot Per Jakobsen.i got it.

Comment: Hi...In my code i m hardcode the listitem.If i used SPListItem item=properties.ListItem; its make some issue becoz it was written inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges.So i need to take listitems without using properties.ListItem.Plz help me

Comment: Replace 84 with `properties.ListItemId`

Comment: thanx a lot Per Jakobsen.

Comment: How to get a list dynamically insead of this coding SPList list = web.Lists["SampleEvent"];

Comment: To make your code more generic you should get the web using `using (var web = site.OpenWeb(properties.WebId))` and get the list using `var list = web.Lists[properties.ListId];`

Comment: ya i got it.Thanx a lot.I have 1 more query.I have 2 fields in List.But i got only 1st field when i'm use the list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId).I want to take 2nd field also.What i have to do.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, maybe create a new question with your updated code, what you want to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Thanx a lot Per Jakobsen.U did a great job for me.My past question is...I have list in the name 'SampleEvent' with 2 fields.One field is Radiobutton with two choice.(i)yes,(ii)no.I want to make some condition by the choice of radiobutton.So i asked how to take the value of that field.Now i found by this code..String s = item.Fields["Only"].GetFieldValueAsText(item["Only"]);.If u know any other simple way mens.Plz share it.